# Vim: How to get rid of filetype-specific map?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

Edit: [Working version](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/commit/5d980834ba9e06f1f2d84678c31fc97581fe0506).

I've mapped `[[` and `]]` to [my own functions](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/9d83ab244fc17cc824bbdea3f961323c40dc4ef9/.vimrc#L57):

```
nmap <silent> ]] :let &tabstop += 1 <CR> :echo 'tabstop =' &tabstop <CR>
nmap <silent> [[ :let &tabstop -= &tabstop > 1 ? 1 : 0 <CR> :echo 'tabstop =' &tabstop <CR>
```

However, according to `:verbose map [[` these are overridden by `/usr/share/vim/vim72/ftplugin/php.vim`. How do I get rid of the PHP mappings while keeping my own? I've tried

```
autocmd FileType php unmap! [[
autocmd FileType php unmap! ]]
```

according to the [tutorial](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_1%29), but then I get error messages at Vim startup:

```
Error detected while processing FileType Auto commands for "php":
E31: No such mapping
E31: No such mapping
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

[Using `nnoremap`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41752/3645) instead of `nmap` doesn't help.

[Putting the mappings in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/php.vim`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41749/3645) also didn't work. `vim -V` shows:

```
...
finished sourcing /usr/share/vim/vim72/ftplugin/php.vim
...
finished sourcing /home/user/.vim/after/ftplugin/php/php.vim
```

So it does find the supposed override.

Combining `nnoremap` and the "after" script doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specific definitions (filetype-specific, project-specific, ...) shall always be declared local to the current buffer. This is accomplished with the `<buffer>` qualifier for mappings and abbreviations (commands use `-b`, and menus need a specific plugin to emulate this, variables are prefixed by `b:`, and settings shall be set (sic) with `:setlocal`).

Moreover to declare it (i.e. a ft specific definition) local to the buffer, you can use autocommand as you seem to be doing, however I'd recommend instead to use ftplugins. It's much more maintenable, and all the rules regarding the overriding of the various definitions (mappings, etc.) are already taken into account.

```
" => ftplugin/php/php_my_stuff.vim
" headers guards...
...
:nnoremap <silent> <buffer> ]] :setlocal ts+=1<cr>:set ts?<cr>
:nnoremap <silent> <buffer> [[ :setlocal ts-=1<cr>:set ts?<cr>
```

PS: SO, or SU would have been a better fit for such a question.

Comment: This solution actually worked! Just added `<buffer>` to the mapping lines in `˜/.vim/after/ftplugin/php.vim` and that was it.

Comment: Mine has `<buffer>`, but if I look at `:scriptnames`, The file `/usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin/sql.vim` comes right after my ftplugin file and overwrites my mappings.  Any way to make mine not get overwritten?

Comment: @JayK Set `b:did_filetype`, IIRC, to prevent the default ftplugin from being loaded.

Comment: @LucHermitte Actually, I found that putting the file in `.vim/after/ftplugin/` did the trick for me.  From http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41749/159250

Answer (score 2):

I'd try to use hints for overruling the default plugin checks described [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#ftplugin-overrule). To sum it up: drop your mappings plugin file late in the runpath (e.g. `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/php.vim`) to override the global mappings.

Comment: That didn't work; please see the updated question.

Answer (score -1):

did you try to use `nnoremap` instead of `nmap` in your `.vimrc`

```
nnoremap <silent> ]] :let &tabstop += 1 <CR> :echo 'tabstop =' &tabstop <CR>
nnoremap <silent> [[ :let &tabstop -= &tabstop > 1 ? 1 : 0 <CR> :echo 'tabstop =' &tabstop <CR>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It still uses the PHP shortcuts.

Comment: hmm - did you try to do it manually after the plugin was loaded.

Comment: Yep, tried copying them after `:` in a Vim session, and no change.